# Rendering view output into a separate region

Tags: 7, views, theming

For the sake of theming, I need to render the output of a view into a separate region. I could create a view block, but this way I lose the ability to pass contextual arguments to it. Any suggestions?

Comment: What kind of contextual arguments are you passing to the view?  Some of them you can replicate quite easily with the pass default arguent PHP field.

Comment: Maybe using panels would help, they are context aware. I don't have time to develop a proper answer but in such scenario's panels have an edge on blocks. COntexts could also be of help but less flexible than panels, in my very humble opinion.

Comment: @stefgosselin Well, I could rephrase my question as "how to change the target region of a panel?"

Comment: @Chapabu I'm passing taxonomy terms

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of hook for views, you can use [hook_views_pre_execute](http://api.lullabot.com/hook_views_pre_execute) or another one it depends of what you need to do.

See [here](http://api.lullabot.com/group/views_hooks) the list

Comment: I need to send output of a view to another theme region. How can this be accomplished with hooks?

Comment: Your block view is in a region. So if you just have to pass a argument to this block use a hook.

Comment: This way I have to manually parse url, don't I?

Answer (score 1):

I've had to do something along these lines recently.  Here's what I did:

1. Create your view and add the Contextual argument "Has taxonomy term ID"
2. Under "When the filter value is not available" select Provide Default Value-> PHP Code
3. Enter the code below:

   ```
   $node = node_load(arg(1));
   if($node) {
     $tag = $node->field_primary_tag['und']['0']['tid'];
   return $tag;
   } 
   else {
     return;
   }
   ```

On another note - this only works for one taxonomy term, but you should be able to modify the code to fit your needs.

**NOTE***

I would suggest that nourcy's answer is a more Drupal friendly one, and my answer was only a quick fix to my/your problem - PHP in blocks/views etc is generally a bad idea :-p

Comment: Nice trick! I think, bad idea is not a PHP code per se, but an ability to insert it.